# VAT Refund on someone else’s card

Tags: germany, europe, taxes, tax-refunds, vat

My parents have a flight back to home tomorrow. They have some refund receipts (Global Blue) to be shown at the Berlin airport.

Since cash refunds have more fee, we wanted to opt for VISA credit/debit cards. Is it possible that they use my card details? I’m a german resident.

Or is it necessary that the card name matches the passenger’s details?